# How to modify apache VirtualHost in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mod-wsgi

I want to insert some lines in apache  directive of my instances in ElasticBeanstalk. (My instances are 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Python 2.7 for running Django with mod_wsgi).

I have created a file "configuration_httpd.py" :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import fileinput

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

custom_conf = open(current_dir+'/httpd.conf','r').read()

try:
    for line in fileinput.input('/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf', inplace=1):
        if line.startswith('</VirtualHost>'):
            print custom_conf
            print line,
        else:
            print line,
except OSError:
    print "Error '/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf' unknown"
```

It's executed on deployments with .ebextensions/django.config file :

```
packages:
  yum:
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
    libpng-devel: []

container_commands:
  01_setup_apache:
    command: "python configure_httpd.py"
  02_migrate:
    command: "python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  03_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "djangoproject.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/djangoproject:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "djangoproject/wsgi.py"
```

This file is executed but the file '/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf' is intact.

Why ?

When I log into my instance with ssh I can run the script "configure_httpd.py" with sudo and it works.

Why this script doesn't work at deployment ?

Any help please. Thank you

Comment: This is a permission issue because when you deploy you do not deploy as the root user and the config file must be owned by root. You have to check if this command will work "sudo python manage.py collectstatic --noinput" in python command.

Comment: It's not a permission issue. After some test, I understand that the file is well modified but is rewrited after container_commands.

Comment: So is the issue fixed for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours on google, I find that the directive `<Directory>` allows to use rewrite rules from outside `<VirtualHost>` directives. Exemple :

```
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
</Directory>
```

Put this in a file and copy it in /etc/httpd/conf.d in container_commands.